# angular2 - Best way to terminate a observable interval when path changes

Tags: typescript, angular, observable

I am using an observable interval to execute an certain function every fifth second within a certain component, related to a path in my route configuration.

```
Observable.interval(5000).subscribe(res => {
    // Something happens here
});
```

However I want to terminate the interval when the path changes. Now it just continues to execute the task...

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could unsubscribe from the subscription (the return object of the subscribe method) in such case:

```
var subscription = Observable.interval(5000).subscribe(res => {
    // Something happens here
});

// to be called when the route changes
subscription.unsubscribe();
```

Because the observable is cold and there will no more subscription, the observable will be disposed...

You can leverage the "routerOnDesactivate" hook method in your component to unsubscribe. It's the hook that let you know when you leave the route component within the routing context.

See this link for more details:

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/OnDeactivate-interface.html

Comment: This seems fair, but how do I know when the route changes from within the component?

Comment: You can leverage the routerOnDesactivate hook method in your component to unsubscribe. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A great way to solve this is to create the observable in a variable and use the '| async' pipe to subscribe and show the value on the template. Unsubscribing is then all taken care of by the pipe.